# Netbeans Visual Library export using PNGJ

Tags: java, netbeans, png

I found out about [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/wiki/Overview) in a SO post. The advantage it offers, especially in memory efficiency, is really what I looked for.

Now I'm going to implement it to capture scene from Netbeans Visual Library. Scrolling down into the [docs](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-visual/org/netbeans/api/visual/widget/doc-files/documentation.html#ExportingWithoutOffscreenBuffer) I found this statement :

> Exporting without Offscreen Buffer
>
> > The previous code uses a BufferedImage for storing the image in the memory. When the scene is big, it could happen that the image does not fit into the memory. Therefore you have to use your Graphics2D instance and Scene.paint (Graphics2D) method for exporting the scene on-the-fly e.g. PDF writer, SVG file writer or meta graphics file writer.

Yeah it is indeed in cooperation with PNGJ : avoiding usage of BufferedImage. But I have no idea how to implement "your Graphics2D" and send it to PNGJ.

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with  Netbeans Visual Library, but I cannot make much sense of that bit about "using your Graphics2D instance" to avoid using much memory with a `BufferedImage`. In any case, `Scene.paint (Graphics2D)` will paint all objects in arbitrary order, so you need to have the full destination available, you cannot stream anything. It's not a PNGJ thing, `Scene.paint()` relies on the `java.awt.*` to do the high level rendering, so you cannot escape from that.

The only workaround I can think of is to try to do partial paints, rendering succesive horizontal stripes (to a BufferedImage) and write them (concatenating them) with PNGJ. But I'm not sure if that's possible, and the performance will probably suffer.

You could also try some "swapped on disk" Image implementation, as [DiskMemImage](https://code.google.com/p/jaitools/wiki/DiskMemImage)

Comment: Yeah, I skimmed through PNGJ source and everytime I encounter `Graphics2D`, there will always be a `BufferedImage`. I can also understand that "you need to have the full destination available" notion, that's why I was hoping that there's another `Graphics2D` (aside from `BufferedImage`'s) to utilise. I will try DiskMemImage, wish me luck.

Anyway, thanks for your response :)